# Making a part of a graph transparent

Tags: vba, excel

I've been using VBA macros to create speedometers/gauges out of two graphs.
The back graph, which is created properly, is a doughnut chart with the lower half made white (and therefore invisible, as this one keeps its background).
The front graph is a pie chart, and I must make some of the elements in the graph invisible (the colored parts).
I can't find much information on anything of the sort. I've been using `myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(2)`.

Comment: Forget about VBA for a while. Can you get the effect you want by doing something like right-clicking on one of the charts and adjusting a transparency setting of chart area or some such thing? If you can figure out what to do by hand -- do so with the macro recorder turned on. Look at the resulting code. Ideally you shouldn't *use* the resulting code, but inspect it to get a feel for where in the chart's object model you need to go to do what you want to do.

Comment: E.g.: `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(2).Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse`

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks, that helped with making them fit smoothly. However, I need to make some of the visible values/colors/etc of the chart transparent too - if you can submit an answer containing that, I'll accept it!

Comment: "some of the visible values/colors/etc of the chart" - examples?  Exactly what do you mean here?

Comment: @TimWilliams Say I create a pie chart with values 180, 1, and 179. I need to make the 180 and 179 invisible on the pie chart. I'm unsure if there's an actual name for those fragments of the chart.

Comment: I would try as @JohnColeman suggests: use the macro recorder and see what code get produced.